# How do you implement databases about history in sql server?

Tags: t-sql, date, datetime

I'm trying to model some ancient history in SQL Server. Do I have to use numeric to refer to the ancient dates like the formation of first life on Earth?

Answer (score 0):

Since date values of ancient history are often given with stuff like 'about 40000 to 30000 B.C.' and such stuff it would be good to have a start and end date. Also it would be good to use single columns for year month day and so on as integers, in order to be able to represent year values like '-40000'.

Comment: I meant ot refer to the problem of overflows using dateadd. For now, I've resorted to using nvarchars.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do what the Sql Server developers did for `DateTime` - you choose an [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)), and store a number to specify the distance from that Epoch.

The Sql Server Epoch for DateTime is the date you get when selecting `SELECT CAST(0 AS DateTime)` - that returns January 1st 1900 at midnight - `1900-01-1T00:00:00`.

Since you are dealing with prehistoric times, you might want to choose `0001-01-01` as your Epoch, just to make the math easy.
Also, prehistoric dates are often estimated ranges, so you would probably want to keep a couple of columns - one for the range start and one for the range end.

I wouldn't suggest under any circumstances to keep dates as strings, that will only get you it trouble.